# What does the ROM files (FACTORYFS, HIDDEN, CACHE, PARAM, etc.) mean?

Tags: rom-flashing, kernel, heimdall, factory-image

Flashing my Galaxy S 2 `i9100` (after breaking with CyanogenMod update `CM-13.x`) I used the following command:

```
sudo heimdall flash \
    --FACTORYFS factoryfs.img \
    --CACHE cache.img \
    --HIDDEN hidden.img \
    --MODEM modem.bin \
    --PARAM param.lfs \
    --BOOT boot.bin \
    --SBL1 Sbl.bin \
    --no-reboot \
    --KERNEL zImage
```

#### Question

I'm wondering what's the role of the different files?

**update**: I encourage you to use `CM-12.1` instead of `CM-13` for your `i9100` as the later is not officially supported.

Comment: HIDDEN is the preload partition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### From [[INFO] What the ROM files mean](http://www.alliance-rom.com/threads/info-what-the-rom-files-mean.2658/)

> **boot.bin** This is the Primitive Bootloader. Seems to make some basic
>   initializations and finally loads the secondary bootloader.
>
> **Sbl.bin** The Secondary Bootloader. It loads the PIT, the Linux kernel,
>   params.lfs and the modem. It also is responsible when the device is
>   charging while it's off. This file contains the picture you see when
>   in Download-mode. So it's also responsible for the flashing stuff and
>   getting into recovery.
>
> The Sbl.bin seems to be there twice. The second one may be for backup,
>   if something bad's going on.
>
> **param.lfs** A collection of JPEGs. These include the Galaxy S-Logo you
>   see first when booting the phone as well as the phone-!-computer
>   picture, the loading spinner and some pictures of an Android giving
>   some information: "CP CRASH UPLOAD MODE", "FORCED UPLOAD by KEY
>   PRESSING", "POWER RESET or UNKNOWN UPLOAD MODE", "USER FAULT Not
>   KERNEL PANIC UPLOAD MODE" and "KERNEL PANIC UPLOAD MODE". And there is
>   the Logo of NTT docomo, which is a Japanese mobile operator company.
>
> Maybe there are more information in this file, but I didn't extract
>   it.
>
> The rest of the files should be rather obvious:
>
> **zImage** is the Linux kernel.
>
> **recovery** Backup Kernel. Don't know if it's
>   used on every device.
>
> **factoryfs.rfs** is the System partition with the
>   Android system.
>
> **dbdata.rfs** is the partition where the app data get
>   stored.
>
> **cache.rfs** is for Dalvik cache.
>
> **modem.bin** is the Modem.

#### From [How to Use Heimdall – specifically on Samsung Captivate – Download 512 513 and 803 PIT files](http://ram.kossboss.com/how-to-use-heimdall-specifically-on-samsung-captivate-download-512-513-and-803-pit-files/)

> - **`IBL+PBL`** is the boot loader, be extra careful with it;
> - **`PIT`** is the partition table;
> - **`EFS`** contains some important data like IEMEI, be extra careful with it;
> - **`SBL`** is the second boot loader;
> - **`SBL2`** is the backup of the second boot loader;
> - **`PARAM`** contains some images used as various stage of the boot process;
> - **`KERNEL`** is the kernel;
> - **`RECOVERY`** is the backup of the kernel;
> - **`FACTORYFS`** contains /system file system which is some kind of root file system;
> - **`DBDATA`** contains /data file system which is the database to store application parameters;
> - **`CACHE`** contains /cache file system which contains the Dalvik cache;
> - **`MODEM`** contains the firmware for the modem.